# Canvas - How to find a point on line from a distance

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've been working on this game that can move a gun towards where the cursor is. However, all I've got to is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Block Shooter</title>
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
        <center>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
            <script>
            // Variables

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var start = false;
            var gunWidth = 80;
            var gunLength = 150;

            $("#canvas").mousemove((event) => {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = gunWidth;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                //get dimensions of canvas. 
                var dimensions=event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                var middle=dimensions.left+(dimensions.width/2)
                ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
                //get mousex relative to canvas
                var mousex=event.offsetX
                //get mousey relative to canvas 
                var mousey=event.offsetY

                var ydistance=mousey;
                var xdistance=mousex-middle
                //distance formula 
                var distance=Math.sqrt((xdistance*xdistance)+(ydistance*ydistance))

                var gunlength=200;
                var drawx=(gunlength*(xdistance/distance))+middle
                var drawy=gunlength*(ydistance/distance)

                ctx.lineTo(drawx, drawy);

                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

            })

            </script>
        </center>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now, somehow it's not pointing correctly and stops moving. Is there a solution for this? Please provide an example. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more information as it is not at all clear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Blindman67 It's updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the [maths described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1630886) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), then you end up with code like this:

```
const x0 = canvas.width * 0.5;
const y0 = canvas.height;

const x1 = event.offsetX;
const y1 = event.offsetY;

const distance = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0)) + ((y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0)));

const t = gunLength / distance;
const x = ((1 - t) * x0) + (t * x1);
const y = ((1 - t) * y0) + (t * y1);

ctx.lineTo(x, y);
```

[Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/uj4for00/)